# Unable to search on whole database with searchkick as it limits to 10000 records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

Unable to search on whole elastic search DB just by using

```
SearchData.search('yamaha', match: :word_middle,load: false)
```

This limits the search to 10000 records but in my DB there are more than a hundred thousand records so, how to search on the whole DB not just the first ten thousand records I'm not able to find anything a little help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure your [indexing](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#indexing) completed successfully? How many docs you have in ES?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about searckick but Elasticsearch always search on entire index and not only 10000 recored but by default it returns only 10 documents in response. You can change response size by changing `size` parameters and max it return 10000 documents per request.

Also, if you have large index then it always show 10000 for `hits.total.value` in response and for getting actual number count you can set `track_total_hits` value to `true`.

```json
{
  "track_total_hits": true,
  "query": {
    "match" : {
      "user.id" : "elkbee"
    }
  }
}
```

If you need to get more then 10000 documents from the Elasticsearch then you can use  `search_after` or `scroll` API. you can refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/paginate-search-results.html#search-after) documentation for more details.

Comment: But that's the real challenge that data is in the DB but still it's not searchable I have no idea why this is happening

Comment: I dont have any idea about searchkick, I have written answer for Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

**Deep Paging**

By default, **Elasticsearch** and OpenSearch limit paging to the first **10,000** results. Here’s why. We don’t recommend changing this, but if you really need all results, you can use:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick deep_paging: true
end
```

If you just need an accurate total count, you can instead use:

```
Product.search("pears", body_options: {track_total_hits: true})
```

Comment: Not sure why the data is not searchable as I can see in the db but when I run the search query `SearchData.search('yamaha', match: :word_middle,load: false)
 ` it won't search not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Searhkick only limits the *results* to 10,000. It will still search on all records in your model, even if the number is well over 10,000.

If you aren't seeing the results you expect, there is something else wrong with your setup.

Have you included searchkick in your model and reindexed?

```
class YourModel < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick
end
```

And in a new console: `YourModel.reindex`